# Perl - Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match

Tags: perl, grep

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to suppress / correct what is causing the warning `"Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match"` in my perl script.

Here is the unit testing script where the warnings are being produced

**Interview.t**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Test::More tests => 16;
use v5.10;
use Data::Dumper;

require_ok('Interview');

# Test URLs
my $test_urls = {
    'http://www.reddit.com'  => 1,
    'hurrdurrimasheep'       => 0
};

my $interview = new Interview;

# Test $interview to see if it's an instance of our 'Interview' class
isa_ok($interview, 'Interview');

# Test to see if $interview has the member functions 'a' and 'b'
can_ok($interview, qw/a b/);

eval { $interview->a; };

cmp_ok($@, '=~', /Oh boy, thats blown to bits/, 'Interview->a dies as expected when no url argument is given.');

eval { $interview->b; };

cmp_ok($@, '=~', /Rubbish/, "Interview->b dies as expected when there are no results in Interview->{'r'}");

# Test to see if the return value from $interview's 'a' member function 
# will either be '1' or '0'.
foreach my $url (keys $test_urls) {
    cmp_ok($interview->a($url), 'eq', $test_urls->{$url}, "Got expected result for Interview->a($url): [ $test_urls->{$url} ]");
}

open(STDOUT, ">/dev/null") || die "Can't redirect stdout";
my $interview_url_results = $interview->b;
close(STDOUT);

my $num_test_urls      = keys scalar $test_urls;
my $num_interview_urls = keys scalar $interview_url_results;

cmp_ok($num_test_urls, '==', $num_interview_urls, "Got expected number of urls returned from Interview->b(): [ $num_test_urls ]");

# The following test ensures that the Interview->b() member function
# is storing the codes returned from Interview->a() correctly.

foreach my $url (keys $interview_url_results) {
    my $expected_code = $test_urls->{$url};
    my $returned_code = $interview->{'r'}->{$url};

    cmp_ok($expected_code, '==', ($returned_code == 200 ? 1 : 0), "Got expected http code from Interview->b() for $url");
}

done_testing;
```

**Interview.pm**

```
package Interview;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my $c = shift;

    return bless {}, $c;
}

sub a {
    my ($self, $u) = @_;
    die 'Oh boy, thats blown to bits' if ! $u;

    my $c = "curl -sL -w '%{http_code} %{url_effective}' '$u' -o /dev/null";
    `$c` =~ /^(\d+)\s/;
    $self->{'r'}->{$u} = $1;

    return $self->{'r'}->{$u} == 200 ? 1 : 0;
}

sub b {
    my $self = shift;
    die 'Rubbish' if ! $self->{'r'};

    foreach my $u (keys %{$self->{'r'}}) {
       print "Results: $u -- $self->{'r'}->{$u}\n";
    }
    return $self->{'r'};
}

1;
```

**Output:**

```
[  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ ~/Development/Interview ]: perl Interview.t
1..10
ok 1 - require Interview;
ok 2 - The object isa Interview
ok 3 - Interview->can(...)
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at Interview.t line 27.
ok 4 - Interview->a dies as expected when no url argument is given.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at Interview.t line 31.
ok 5 - Interview->b dies as expected when there are no results in Interview->{'r'}
ok 6 - Got expected result for Interview->a(hurrdurrimasheep): [ 0 ]
ok 7 - Got expected result for Interview->a(http://www.reddit.com): [ 1 ]
ok 8 - Got expected number of urls returned from Interview->b(): [ 2 ]
ok 9 - Got expected http code from Interview->b() for hurrdurrimasheep
ok 10 - Got expected http code from Interview->b() for http://www.reddit.com
```

You can see the warnings right after test 3 and 4. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please provide the minimum code and data to reproduce the problem in the future.

Comment: Will do! Thanks for the tip

Comment: Not only will help us, it will help you identify the problem for yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The warning is coming from the following line:

```
cmp_ok($@, '=~', /Oh boy, thats blown to bits/, ...);
```

You want to pass a regex pattern to `cmp_ok`, but instead, you pass a value indicating whether `$_` contains `Oh boy, thats blown to bits` or not. The warning comes from the fact that you never assigned anything to `$_`. But the real problem is that you should have used

```
cmp_ok($@, '=~', qr/Oh boy, thats blown to bits/, ...);
```

But that still suffers from a second problem. When no exceptions occur, `$@` will be `undef`, so `cmp_ok` will issue a warning when it checks the pattern against `$@`. `like` is not only simpler in this case, but it handles `undef` without a warning.

```
like($@, qr/Oh boy, thats blown to bits/, ...);
```

Comment: Nod to Andy Lester for `like`.

Answer (score 5):

Like @ikegami points out, this line:

```
cmp_ok($@, '=~', /Oh boy, thats blown to bits/);
```

should actually be:

```
cmp_ok($@, '=~', qr/Oh boy, thats blown to bits/);
```

because `qr/xxx/` is a regex scalar, but `/xxx/` actually evaluates the regex against `$_`.

However, an even better solution is to use the `like()` function rather than `cmp_ok()`.

```
like($@, qr/Oh boy, thats blown to bits/);
```

Answer (score 2):

Line 27 is:

```
cmp_ok($@, '=~', /Oh boy, thats blown to bits/, 'Interview->a dies as expected when no url argument is given.');
```

So, what's in `$@` at this point? I would guess - `eval { $interview->a; };` is returning undef. So you might want to test if it's `defined` first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `qr` operator to define a regex and not a match. If you use `/regex/`, you want to match it immediately, but you want the operator `=~` to be used with the two arguments. This line would give the wanted result:

```
cmp_ok($@, '=~', qr/Oh boy, thats blown to bits/, 'Interview->a dies as expected when no url argument is given.');
```